# Which code to use to capture picture(s) from a video on Android (Phonegap)

Tags: android, image, cordova, video

I am developing an app on Android (Phonegap) in order to capture pictures from a video.

My code below is working for a web page but not with Phonegap. I just see a black rectangle on my app.

Is it possible to take a snapshot of a video with Phonegap?

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');            
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');            
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function snap() {                
    context.fillRect(0,0,150,100);                
    context.drawImage(video,0,0);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/sebible/cordova-videosnapshot

**From the documentation:**

```
    function success(result) {
    if (result && result.result) {
        for (var i in result.snapshots) {
            var absfilepath = result.snapshots[i];
            // Do whatever you want with absfilepath
            // Maybe assign to a img
            // $("<img>").attr("src", absfilepath).appendTo("body");
        }
    }
}

function fail(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

// This generates 3 snapshots of the source video no matter what its duration is (with timestamps printed at the lower right)
var options = {
    source: "file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/0.mp4",
    count: 3,
    timeStamp: true
}

sebible.videosnapshot.snapshot(success, fail, options);

// This generates 3 snapshots for every minute of the source video (with timestamps as well).
var options2 = {
    source: "file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/0.mp4",
    countPerMinute: 3,
    timeStamp: true
}

sebible.videosnapshot.snapshot(success, fail, options2);
```